# Which graphics card should I use for Photoshop (nVIDIA or Intel)?

Tags: photoshop, computer-hardware

Can you please give me some advice about these video  integrated graphics cards:
1. nVIDIA GeForce
2. Intel HD Graphics

Which one is better to use photoshop? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Generally I believe Intel HD is a "cheap" solution (giving good results for common tasks like HD video, though), while Nvidia is more powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to use Photoshop CS5, which has the ability to use the graphics card for some of its processing, then the latest drivers for the nVidia GT 320M (for Windows XP and up) enable the support for it in the card. I've had a hard time finding out if that is also true of the Intel HD.

So... If I had to pick, with all other things being equal, I'd go with the nVidia one. Now, I'm not sure if the two are otherwise equal (I didn't find English sites with detailed specs), so bear in mind that other factors may also play a role. Available RAM, number of cores, CPU speed, and a host of other factors do play into overall performance though you can ignore this if the two are quite close.

Final thought, the two previous postings have valid points. The notebook will give the horsepower you want, but the display will still be less than ideal for actual editing. You'll definitely want a good monitor when editing at home and you'll want to profile both.

Comment: +1 for this, both for mentioning GPU computing and noting that other factors may be more important. But I don't believe current Intel offerings provide any GPGPU capabilities. Their graphics offerings have always been far less powerful, so it's unclear if there would be a big benefit from doing at this point anyway.

Comment: @mattdm - I tend to agree, though Adobe does mention Intel cards in their basic info on the feature. It wasn't clear, though, if this one had it or not. I tend to trust to nVidia over Intel for graphics anyways, so that would be the path I'd take unless the tech specs on the other were so clearly better otherwise (and I doubt it).

Comment: Thank you for you mention. The laptops are same, but they have different processors, the one with Intel Graphics card has an Intel® CoreTM i3 350M processor and the other has an Intel Pentium T4500 processor. I think the first one is much better. So do you think I have to use the one with Intel graphics card?

Comment: @Tojass - Yeah, the i3 350M specs definitely appear to be a cut above the T4500, but looking at some benchmarks (Tom's Hardware) on the desktop versions of those CPU, I'm not sure that it is a difference that will have a huge advantage in Photoshop. You might also want to read this: http://blogs.pcmag.com/miller/2010/04/how_adobe_cs5_takes_advantage.php as it may make the nVidia option more compelling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have read the site you told me, but I don't know which one to choose... Do you think for photoshop the T4500 is better?

Comment: @Tojass - At this point, I'd be recommending on the video card, I think, so probably the one with nVidia inside.

Answer (score 3):

Far more important is the actual display itself, and how the signal gets there. If you're serious about photographic editing, you should at least be using a colorimeter to get an accurate colour profile for your display; better still, you'd be using a wide-gamut display, something like the NEC MultiSync PA271W which has a good reputation.

Comment: Please read my edit.

Comment: That used to be the case but Adobe is integrating more and more GPU enhancements into Photoshop so the graphics card may start mattering a lot in future - http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405745.html

Answer (score 2):

The graphics card is not that important - but if you want, of course the nVidia will have better support/software then the Intel. (Though I don't know why Intel neglected the field.)

I won't check the Laptops, but look for dual core and a digital video out to connect to a proper high res and color stable monitor (LED lighting for semi-stable color, MVA/PVA/IPS-LCD-technology instead of TN) - as Rowland said, the monitor and how the signal gets there is much more important for good photo-work than the hardware in system. I'd guess the laptops have only a TN LCD display - colors will vary a lot with viewing angle, greyscale is not stable.